# Access certificates installed from SD card of Android devices

Tags: android, security, pki, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-keystore

I try to access PKI secured services on Android using Java. Certificates were installed on devices through ***settings->location & security ->Install*** from SD card.

Seems like on ICS, certificates are shared under ***/system/etc/security/cacerts*** while on GingerBread they are in a keystore: ***/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks***.

On ICS I found the [KeyChain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) can read all the installed certificates, so my question is:

Is there a way to access certificates installed from SD card on **OS < level 14**?

or

If there is a unified way to access certificates installed from SD card on **OS >= level 8?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access those, because only the system user(s) have permission to. However, they are not really useful for third party apps, because only the WiFi and VPN daemons can use them. If you want your own keystore, you can create one for your app and set up HttpClient/URLConnection to use it.

Some more details here:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: Thanks. I am creating a keystore for those certificates now.

Comment: It is working for me now, you can find some details under "access certificates installed from SD card on OS < level 14" from Android's forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-security-discuss

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access those,
because only the sytem user(s)
have permission to. However,
they are not really usefull for
Third party apps, because only
only the Wifi and VPN daemons can
Use them. If want your own
keystore, you can create one for 
your app and set up HttpClient/
UTL connection to use it.